# Creating desktops on EWMH/NetWM standard with Bash

Tags: bash, openbox

I want to develop a script to add/rename/remove desktops, probably assign shortcuts to them as well. Like this pager https://github.com/BurntSushi/pager-multihead. There's some way of doing that through Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wmctrl` or `xdotool` for adding and removing desktops.

Both tools can only change the number of desktops. That means you have to first you need to get the number of desktops.

```
num_of_desk=$(wmctrl -d | wc -l)
num_of_desk=$(xdotool get_num_desktops)
```

and then you have to increase the number by one to add a new desktop

```
wmctrl -n $(( num_of_desk + 1 ))
xdotool set_num_desktops $(( num_of_desk + 1 ))
```

or decrease by one to remove the last desktop

```
wmctrl -n $(( num_of_desk - 1 ))
xdotool set_num_desktops $(( num_of_desk - 1 ))
```

Both tools do not allow you to rename the desktop or rearrange them.